# Replace 'ShowDialog' method to return specific data?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, showdialog

I'm using a *TopMost* Form that when its Shown it just waits for the **OnMouseDown** to select an area on the screen and on the **OnMouseUp** event I close the Form, then my intention is to return a **Rectangle** that contains the selected area after the **OnMouseUp** event ...when the Form closes using a **ShowDialog** call.

Something like this:

```
Dim Rect As Rectangle = MyForm.ShowDialog
```

So I've thinked that overriding/replacing properly the **ShowDialog** function to return other DataType could be the most efficient way, but I didn't know how to done it properly, I need a code-example.

PS: I think this way is better than adding hardcoded methods to reproduce the same function, but I'm open to other alternatives.

Comment: why cant the Rect be a property of the form?  onMouseup, just hide and the caller can get the Rect from a `SelectionRectangle Property` then, close the dialog.  Easier.

Comment: yes @Plutonix The rectangle is already a public property, I could use the `ShowDialog` and after the call I could retrieve the property, something like: `MyForm.ShowDialog() : Dim Rect As Rectangle = MyForm.SelectionRectangle`, maybe I like to do things harder but I have the whim to use the Form as I've mentioned, I would like to know if it's possible, thanks for your comment.

Comment: If you are asking if you can write the statement as shown, the answer is no.  ShowDialog returns DialogResult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do this. When you override a method in a derived class, you cannot change the type of value it returns. In more technical terms, you cannot change the *signature* of the method as defined in the base class.

What you *can* do is return a more specific derived type, but that won't help in this case. You can't inherit from `DialogResult` and it wouldn't serve any purpose even if you could.

The other thing you can do is *overload* a method. I have done this with the `ShowDialog` method before. In a derived class, I added an additional overload that accepted one or more parameters, which the dialog then used to initialize itself before displaying. That can be a pretty slick design—I certainly thought so at the time—but it's not without its compromises. But that is not what you're asking here.

Anyway, even if you could change the return type of the `ShowDialog` method, it would be a bad idea to do it. I can think of two *good* reasons off the top of my head, and one bonus reason:

1. You cannot determine *how* the user closed the dialog. The standard dialog is going to have a confirm ("OK"/"Yes") button and a cancel ("Cancel"/"Close"/"No") button. You only want to do the action if the user pressed the confirm button. If they pressed the cancel button, you want to bail out.

   If you return a different type from `ShowDialog`, you'll need to figure out a way of signaling whether the dialog was canceled. What are you going to return as the rectangle (or whatever) if the dialog was canceled?

   You'd end up doing some nonsense like returning a `Nullable<Rectangle>`, and you're no better off than where you started.
2. If you use it like the sample code shown in the question, you'll forget to call the `Dispose` method on your dialog form and leak resources.

   This is an important one that lots of WinForms programmers forget. When you close a normal, non-modal form, the `Dispose` method is called automatically. But it is *not* called automatically for modal dialogs, shown using the `ShowDialog` method. In that case, you have to call `Dispose` yourself manually. (Why, you might ask? Simple, because after the dialog is closed, you almost always want to read values from its properties, which you can't do if it has been disposed.)

   So the standard idiom for showing a modal dialog is this one; I highly encourage you to use it:

   ```
   Using myDialog As New MyDialogForm
       If (myDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK)
           ' Do whatever it is you want to do, including
           ' reading the values of properties of myDialog.
           '
           ' For example:
           Dim rect As Rectangle = myDialog.SelectedRectangle
           ' ...
       End If
   End Using
   ```

   With the [`Using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx), you don't have to call the `Dispose` method yourself, it gets handled automatically, *even if an exception is thrown*. This is nothing unusual and should not be unexpected. `Using` statements are how you deal with *any* resource that implements `IDisposable`. Modal dialogs are no exception.
3. It is a non-standard idiom, highly likely to confuse future maintenance programmers. People expect it to return a `DialogResult` value. Even if you don't care about other people, if you are anything like me, when you return to look at code you've written 3 months from now, it might as well have been the first time you've ever seen it.

**TL;DR:** No, just add a regular old property to the derived Form class you're showing as a modal dialog.

Comment: +1 for the Using block on dialogs, I had forgotten that

Comment: @Cody Gray That is one of the most useful answer that I've received in all the time here, some things I already knew like the usage of 'Dispose' method for Dialogs but I just shown an easier example to read for people than using 'Using' bloks, just a question, what means the abbreviatures 'TL' and 'DR' for non-english people like me?, really thanks for explaining all the needed things.

Comment: @Elektro It stands for "too long; didn't read". Sometimes people complain that my answers are too long, so I'll sometimes add that as a bit of a joke. It's just a summary.